# Cannot load Handlebars helper function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to create a custom hbs helper and use it in my page for my express.js application. Here is how I do it but it keeps saying :

> Missing Helper "if_eq"

My page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="javascripts/handlebars-v4.0.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/hbs_funcs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {{#if_eq page "home"}}
            <li class="active"><a  href="/home ">LOBBY</a></li>
    {{else}}
            <li><a  href="/home ">LOBBY</a></li>
   {{/if_eq}}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my hbs js file:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function (a, b, opts) {
if (a == b) // Or === depending on your needs
    return opts.fn(this);
else
    return opts.inverse(this);
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by moving the function to the server side like this:

```
var hbs = exphbs.create({
defaultLayout: 'main', //we will be creating this layout shortly
helpers: {
    if_eq: function (a, b, opts) {
        if (a == b) // Or === depending on your needs
            return opts.fn(this);
        else
            return opts.inverse(this);
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score -2):

The HBS template was rendered in the backend, but your helper is registered in frontend. Register the helper where you are using it.